# how to run existing C file onto Xcode have

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal

I'm new on Xcode.
I need to make some files run:
they are the implementation of a model that I'd like to apply on my dataset, but at the moment I cannot use them.

Inside the folder there are:

```
main.cc,  Makefile, README
```

and other files with extentions

.cc, 
  .c, 
  .h, 
  .yld, 
  .lt

How do I put them on Xcode? And how can I run them from the Terminal?
I have:

OS X El Capitan;
Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: If you have a Makefile, do you really need to mess with Xcode? You mean you just want to add the source files to an existing Xcode project? What does the README say?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your build target to be the makefile, but, this will not give you all of Xcode's benifits as an IDE. As far as I know, importing a Makefile based project into Xcode is not easy.

Here is a [blog post](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/08/01/simple-c-plus-plus-from-makefiles-to-xcode-builds/) detailing one example.

You could create a new project with your desired language, and add files to it.

As for how to run from terminal, you `cd` to project directory, and then you type `make`. Then you find name of the program created, and you type `./[PROGRAM]` to execute it.